# time(*time_t) does not get current time (homework)

Tags: c++, c

we are making some reports about different sorting algorithms. They're all working, but I get an error when printing the processing time for merge sort

I wrote the following code

```
...BubbleSort(arr3,50000);

time(&time_now); 
f = difftime(time_now,time_then);
printf("BubbleSort - tempo: %f\n",f);

time(&time_then); 
printf("then: %s",ctime(&time_then));
MergeSort(arr4,0,49999);

time(&time_now); 
printf("now: %s",ctime(&time_now)); 
f = difftime(time_now,time_then);

printf("MergeSort - tempo: %f\n",f);
```

but it always says time = 0s for merge sort

[image]

it seems it can't get the current time or mergesort's processing time is really low (but it works)
thanks in advance

Comment: What does your implementation of `MergeSort` look like?  Also, `time` will probably not give you the needed precision for faster operations.  `clock()` is more commonly used to do this kind of comparison ... or a high precision timer from boost.

Comment: You already have a hypthesis ("is really low") so why dont you test it by e.g. sorting more data?

Comment: `difftime()` returns the difference in seconds (although return value is `double`...). Between `time_then` and `time_now` is 0 seconds difference as you can see on the output. So all works right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see zeros because your `MergeSort` is so fast that it completes in under a measurable time interval on your system.

Giving your program substantially more data to sort should help. Alternatively, you could change the time measurement mechanism for something more precise. The second approach is system-dependent, though.

The execution time for `MergeSort` grows as N*log<sub>2</sub>(N), so to see a time comparable with that of `BubbleSort` which grows as N<sup>2</sup>, you need to give it significantly more data. For an array of 50,000 items the math works out to approximately 3,000 *times* the size. If you pass `MergeSort` an array of roughly 50,000*3,000=150,000,000 items, you should see a non-zero number printed.

Note: Do not try passing that much data to `BubbleSort` - it would take it ages to complete, unless the data is already pretty close to being sorted.

Comment: @maxpesa:  You could get higher precision by using platform-specific timing functions, such as `QueryPerformanceCounter` under Windows.  Or you could use Boost, which does the same but wraps it all up in a platform-agnostic way.

Answer (score 6):

Do not use `time` to time the runtime of programs/algorithms. This is the global system time and includes preemption time and other programs running the background.

Use `getrusage` to get the resource (CPU time) usage of your code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>



struct rusage start, end;
getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &start);

// run your code

getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &end);

struct timeval used_utime, used_stime;
timersub(&end.ru_utime, &start.ru_utime, &used_utime);
timersub(&end.ru_stime, &start.ru_stime, &used_stime);
printf("function ran for %d usec in user mode and %d usec in system mode \n"
    , used_utime.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 + used_utime.tv_usec
    , used_stime.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 + used_stime.tv_usec);
```

Comment: @maxpesa 1st check if this would work with your environment!! [getrusage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you want elapsed or CPU time. Following is for both.

```
  // On Raspberry Pi gcc timing.c -lrt -O3 -o timer

  #include <time.h>
  #include <stdio.h>

  double  theseSecs = 0.0;
  double  startSecs = 0.0;
  double  secs;
  double  CPUsecs = 0.0;
  double  CPUutilisation = 0.0;
  double  answer = 0;
  clock_t starts;

  void start_CPU_time()
  {      
      starts = clock();;
      return;
  }

  void end_CPU_time()
  {
      CPUsecs = (double)(clock() - starts)/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      return;
  }    

  struct timespec tp1;
  void getSecs()
  {
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp1);
     theseSecs =  tp1.tv_sec + tp1.tv_nsec / 1e9;           
     return;
  }

  void start_time()
  {
      getSecs();
      startSecs = theseSecs;
      return;
  }

  void end_time()
  {
      getSecs();
      secs    = theseSecs - startSecs;
      return;
  }    

  void calculate()
  {
      int i, j;
      for (i=1; i<100001; i++)
      {
          for (j=1; j<10001; j++)
          {
              answer = answer + (float)i / 100000000.0;
          }
      }
  }

 void main()
 {
     start_time();
     start_CPU_time();
     calculate();
     end_time();
     end_CPU_time();
     CPUutilisation = CPUsecs /  secs * 100.0;
     printf("\n Answer %10.1f, Elapsed Time %7.4f, CPU Time %7.4f, CPU Ut %3.0f%\n",
              answer, secs, CPUsecs, CPUutilisation);  
 }
```

Comment: It looks very clean and neat to me. +1

Answer (score 0):

`time` function and `time_t` type granularity is usually seconds, so if your function returns in less than 1 second the diff will be zero.
For quick and dirty benchmarking you can use `clock()`.